# activate touch gesture with a php embedded map

Tags: php, android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm creating an AIR app. 
I've got a map at this address : http://www.cocogeek.nc/mapBateau.php

the code of this page was on MarineTraffic.com. Here it is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    width='100%';       // the width of the embedded map in pixels or percentage
    height='450';       // the height of the embedded map in pixels or percentage
    border='1';     // the width of the border around the map (zero means no border)
    shownames='false';  // to display ship names on the map (true or false)
    latitude='37.4460'; // the latitude of the center of the map, in decimal degrees
    longitude='24.9467';    // the longitude of the center of the map, in decimal degrees
    zoom='9';       // the zoom level of the map (values between 2 and 17)
    maptype='3';        // use 0 for Normal map, 1 for Satellite, 2 for Hybrid, 3 for Terrain
    trackvessel='0';    // MMSI of a vessel (note: vessel will displayed only if within range of the system) - overrides "zoom" option
    fleet='';       // the registered email address of a user-defined fleet (user's default fleet is used)
    remember='false';   // remember or not the last position of the map (true or false)
    language='en';      // the preferred display language
    showmenu=true;      // show or hide the map options menu
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.marinetraffic.com/js/embed.js"></script>
```

Now I'm building an AIR app and I would like to make this map accessible by users.

Here's my AS3 code :

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;

    var webView:StageWebView;
    var swvRect:Rectangle;   
    var swvHeight:Number;  
    var swvY:Number=0;

    mainPanel.visible=false;

    init();

    function init():void {

        swvHeight=stage.stageHeight-44;
        mainPanel.x=stage.stageWidth/2-mainPanel.width/2;
        mainPanel.visible=true;

    if(webView!=null){

            return;
        }
         webView=new StageWebView(); 
         webView.stage=this.stage;
         webView.viewPort=new Rectangle(0,swvY,stage.stageWidth,swvHeight);
         webView.loadURL("http://www.cocogeek.nc/mapBateau.php");
    }
```

The page is loading perfectly well.

Problem : The touch gesture doesn't work. If I swipe to the left (or any direction) on the embedded map, it's not working.

Do you know how I can make the touch gesture works on this embedded map ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

A [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) is not a UIComponent, actually not a Flash display object at all and thus does not dispatch gestures events and the normal event capture/bubble cycle do not apply here since the StageWebView instance is not part of the display list.

It is a native web control from the OS that is displayed 'on top' of your AIR controls so whatever gestures are supported via the OS browser and the mobile HTML that is being displayed will be supported within StageWebView's viewport.

Try loading that google map into your Android's browser and does it support swipes?

Comment: No, you're right, even in my Android's browser it doesn't support swipes... So, no solutions ?

Comment: Since it is a google map, it 'should' support some gestures assuming the marine wrapper placed on it is not disabling or overriding them. Try these Google Map Android gestures to see if any of them work: https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/3139292?p=maps_android_gestures